# Regex - what does the infinite error mean?

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I'm sitting in on some technical interviews at the moment and we ask a question about checking that curly brackets are balanced (same number of opens/closes and that closes never proceed their matching open) within a string - asking people to write a small function to verify this.

A few candidates have considered trying to use Regex to solve this, then given up pretty quickly. I decided I wanted to give it a try, to see if it was possible. I'm currently using the following test strings:

### Pass

`{(function(r){ return r; })()}
{}{}{}{}
{{{{}}}}`

### Fail

`}{
{{}}}
{{{}}`

I thought the following regex would work `[^{}]*({[^{}]*})*[^{}]*`. The idea was to match non-curly bracket characters , then match `{` then non-curly bracket characters, then `}`, repeating the bracketed match, and then finish with any non-curly bracket characters.

I seem to be getting an `infinite` error when using regexr.com though and I don't understand why:

[image]

Can anyone explain what is causing this exactly?

Comment: In most regex flavors, `{` and `}` need to be escaped (outside character classes) as they are quantifiers.

Comment: I don't think JavaScript can support arbitrary levels of nesting. Some regex flavors can (because they go beyond standad regex), but not JavaScript's. You could do an expression that could handle (say) up to four levels of nesting, but it would have to be hardcoded.

Comment: "Finite automata can't count" - it *might* be possible to match balanced braces with some modern "regular expression" mechanisms, but I'd be pretty surprised if it were possible with JavaScript.

Comment: @Pointy With Javascript he could us [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), searching for `{` and `}` and counting them inside a function passed as the second parameter of the `replace`

Comment: @xanatos oh yes, it's definitely possible to implement with code, but a "real" regular expression doesn't track state transitions in a way that makes counting balances properly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Afaik if the parser doesn't recognize braces as being a valid quantifier they're matched literally by default in most regex flavors. Only the opening brace needs to be escaped if you want to match eg `{3}` literally: `\{3}`.  For Java probably always need to be escaped.

Comment: Modern day regex engines support a stack for counting. In this case it would be for balanced text. Some engines do this with recursion Perl, PCRE, etc, some do it with counting Dot-Net. Most all other older, outdated engines Java, JavaScript, etc.. do not do this. Bottom line, balanced text (anything) can be tested or matched using modern engines. _It certainly can't be done with your attempt._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an infinite error because your regex can match any text. Since all of your groups are marked with `*`, they are all considered optional (`*` matches zero or more occurrences). This means that the engine can find zero occurrences of any group in your pattern and still consider the text a match.

Consider marking at least one group with `+`, which means "one or more" rather than "zero or more". Try this pattern:

```
[^{}]*(\{[^{}]*\})+[^{}]*
```

This way, the engine has some kind of restriction that it **must** match for your pattern to be accepted.

NOTE: it is also wise to escape `{` and `}` when not in a character block (`[]`). I have done this in the pattern above. Regexr.com doesn't seem to care, but some engines might produce a parse error without them.

Comment: Thanks very much, that does make sense. I maybe need to have a deep dive into how regex implementations work.

Answer (score 0):

***Update***

This is regex you need (one level):

```
\{{0,1}[^\{\}]*\{[^\{\}]*\}[^\{\}]*\}{0,1}
```

I cannot write a nested rule, but you can say how many levels you need.

Explanation:

| - means alternative (a|b - matches "a" or "b" literally)
^ - means start of line (^a - matches any string that begin with "a" literally, "a taxi", "apple" ...)
$ - means end of line (a$ - matches any string that end with "a" literally, "umbrella")
\{ - matches character: "{" literally
\( - matches character: "(" literally

Comment: Would this work for `{hello { world } {it { is { a } nice} day}}`? It's a solution targeted only at the sample inputs, not at the problem in general.

Comment: @Pointy: ah, I see - my mistake. I corrected this, but regex do not support nested rules. I can wrote for him better rule (more levels), but I need to know count of them.

Comment: The point of the question is less about answering how to achieve what I was trying, and more down to "why is this failing". But thanks.